# Match everything before a pattern including including new line and/or carriage return

Tags: java, regex

How can I match everything until a specific group is encountered

Match:

Group1:

`abc def xyz what ever foo blah blah
keep matching this 
and this`

Group 2:

`01 Feb 2018 blah blah blah
keep matching this 
and this 
keep matching this 
and this`

Group 3:

`01 Mar 2018 blah blah blah`

From:

`abc def xyz what ever foo blah blah
keep matching this 
and this 
01 Feb 2018 blah blah blah
keep matching this 
and this 
keep matching this 
and this 
01 Mar 2018 blah blah blah`

match everything right before `01 Jan 2018` the date here is the pattern `([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4})`

this doesn't seems to work `^((.*)(?!([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4})))`

Comment: You forgot to say what pattern you're looking for.

Comment: @shmosel ([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}) is the pattern

Comment: But you said that doesn't work.

Comment: @shmosel it picks up the first line but not the next 2

Comment: Don't use a lookahead assertion, it's too slow. Just match the date but don't capture it `([\S\s]*?)([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4})`

Comment: @sin Your regex is selecting good but it also captures the date in the next line and leaves the rest in next time 
https://regex101.com/r/Yao7Xw/1 , the date should be captured in the next group and used as a pattern to end selection before it.

Comment: @Fenomatik - I put up a solution for you. Let me know if there are any mods needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead and `DOTALL` modifier:

```
(?ms)(.+?(?=^\d{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{4}|\z))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Amnbk1/2)

**Description:**

- `(?ms)`: Enable `DOTALL` modifier so that we can match any characters including newlines using `.`. Also enable `MULTILINE` mode to be able to yse `^` and `$` anchors.
- `.+?`: Match 1 or more characters including newlines
- `(?=^\d{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{4})`: Using lookahead assertion make sure we have a date ahead (in `dd-mon-yyyy` format)

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "(?ms)(.+?(?=^\\d{2}\\s[A-Za-z]{3}\\s\\d{4}|\\z))";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regex );
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( input );

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question , this is more like a log entry , I want to match everything before the date format and then it should pick it up as a new match . The regex you gave me is selecting all in one match

Comment: Did you somehow miss the new line thing ```^```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do now.
To avoid complications, something like this is in order.

`"(?s)(?=.)([0-9]{2}\\s[A-Za-z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4})?.*?(?=(?:[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Za-z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4})|\\z)"`

https://regex101.com/r/xGmVGp/1

Readable regex

```
 (?s)                                    # Dot-all modifier
 (?= . )                                 # Must be a char ahead (avoid empty string)

 (                                       # (1 start), Optional date at the start
      [0-9]{2} \s 
      [A-Za-z]{3} \s 
      [0-9]{4}                    
 )?                                      # (1 end)

 .*?                                     # Optional , non-greedy any amount of characters

 (?=                                     # Assertion
      (?:                                     # Must be a date ahead (new record)
           [0-9]{2} \s 
           [A-Za-z]{3} \s 
           [0-9]{4}                              
      )
   |                                        # or,
      \z                                      # End of string
 )
```

Comment: @Fenomatik - I'm pretty sure you don't understand a thing you even said, Shouldn't the world be round, not an oval or 359 degrees ? I know, it's a riddle, very hard to understand.